# Encode URL using ZXing Library

Tags: android, zxing

Android 2.3.3

I am trying to encode a simple URL using ZXing library.

I Just need to encode the URL field(id = edittext_url_link) in the below file.

Data entered into the fields -> `URL Title = My Website. URL = http://www.mywebsite.com`

XML File :::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_url_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter URL to Encode:"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_url_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="URL Title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_url_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_url_link"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:text="URL" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_url_link"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_url_encode"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Encode"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_url_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java File :::

```
public class URLEncodeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText edtxtURLTitle, edtxtURL;
    Button btnEncode, btnCancel;

    String urlTitle, url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_url);

        edtxtURLTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_url_title);
        edtxtURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_url_link);
        btnEncode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_url_encode);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_url_cancel);


        urlTitle = edtxtURLTitle.getText().toString();
        url = edtxtURL.getText().toString();

        btnEncode.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(v.getId() == R.id.button_url_encode)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Encode.ACTION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, url);
            intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.FORMAT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }

}
```

But, I keep getting a dialogue saying, "Could not encode a barcode from the data provided". What is it that I am doing wrong?

---

[EDIT]

For a future reference, though it is not recommended to import the ZXing library code to your project, i did it and here is the call that i made for the URL to get encoded.

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    "com.xxx.xx.android.ENCODE");
            String data = edtxtURL.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(Const.FROM_ACTIVITY, "URL");
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", Contents.Type.TEXT);
            intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT",
                    BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Vamis Challa have u resolved your issue ?

Comment: @ErumHannan, I imported the library code to my project and used the above code(in edit section) to get my work done.

Comment: can u pls come http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era getting issues in encoding

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to write this yourself, but instead use `IntentIntegrator.shareText()`:
https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java

There is likely some small problem in here that using the standard library call avoids.

If I had to guess beyond that, I'd guess that the URL doesn't actually have "http://" in it or has an extra space or something.

Comment: But the code seems to be clear and the data is fine. I get the same error while trying to encode a Email Address, Phone Number, and other plain things. Does this info, give you an idea on what's happening?

Comment: A small correction in the above comment. The above (approach in question) is working with Phone Numbers and Text. But it is giving errors with Emails and URLs.

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem with URLs. Try sharing a bookmark in Barcode Scanner, or try with ZXing Test. For emails I believe the type needs to be "EMAIL_TYPE"